# how to add image in this canvas its not coming for me please check this?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, canvas

Please tell me how to put this image in canvas and then move it to next form this same image

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function a () {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("Image1");   
   ctx.drawImage(img, 20, 30,10,10); 
   function copy() {
    var imgData = ctx.getImageData("img");
    ctx.putImageData(imgData, 10, 70);
 }
 </script>
</head>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <body onload =a()>
      <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/q.jpg" width="300px" Height="200px"/>
   <canvas id="myCanvas" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
  <button onclick="copy()">Copy</button>
   </body>
  </form>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some issue on your code snippet(for example, body outside the form, andd the tentative to get reference to image from canvas), but to draw image to canvas, manipulate the content of the canvas and then update the source image from the result of canvas manipulation try this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
function a() {
 var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
 var img = document.getElementById("Image1");
 ctx.drawImage(img, 20, 30, 10, 10);
}

function copy() {
 var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
 var imgData = ctx.getImageData(20, 30, 10, 10);
 ctx.putImageData(imgData, 10, 70);

 document.getElementById("Image1").src = c.toDataURL();
 return false;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload =a()>
<!--<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="" width="300px" Height="200px"/>-->
<img src="notfunny.png" id="Image1"/>
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
<button onclick="copy()">Copy</button>
</body>
```

Comment: yeah if we remove this copy function its working just we need to set  the canvas size according to the size of the image na

Comment: so you have to modify this statement from ctx.drawImage(img, 20, 30, 10, 10); to ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, YourDesiredWidth,YourDesiredHeight);